# How to link to database with coordinates to a Google Map

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, geolocation, maps

I have a huge database with geo-coordinates like -73.9637,40.7683 + a Google Map which shows some part of our world.

Now, how to select all coordinates from my database which fit into the part of the map i can see? (Do i get a range from google? how to work with this range?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map.getBounds()` to get the current viewport of your map and do some basic math to search for visible lat/lngs in your database.

Answer (score 0):

you could use google marker manager

[marker manager](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.1/docs/examples.html)